# jquery UI datepicker doesn't show

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this program and i want to add a jquery datepicker on it, but for some reason (maybe its how i put in order the library), it won't show. I created a sample .html file that would only display a datepicker and it shows the datepicker. Here's the code of my .html file (that shows the datepicker):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="css/dynamicMenuTabStyle.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.jqgrid.custom.css" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"/>  


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>
```

datepicker.js code:

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker();
    });
```

And this is my other .html which i wanted to insert my datepicker, (but unfortunately, it won't show):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="css/dynamicMenuTabStyle.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.jqgrid.custom.css" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>     
        <!--this is for my jqgrid-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.fluid.js"></script>
        <!--this is for my other .js files-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="globalFunc.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tallySheet.js"></script>      
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mainindex.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="prime-settings.js"></script>
        <!--this is for my closable tabs-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.tabs.closable.min.js"></script>
```

Please, anybody here know where should i insert the code to display the datepicker? Please help.

**Edit:**

here's my input date inside the body tag (this code is in the two .html file):

```
 date: <input type = "text" id = "date" value= "[select date]" color = "gray">
```

Comment: Could you explain better what the code refers to? It's not so clear... there is no input tag, and what are all those calls to .js in the last code-block?

Comment: Please see my edit. I have my input tag inside the body in the two .html file. The first .html file (the first one in the question) shows the datepicker with this one 'date: <input type = "text" id = "date" value= "[select date]" color = "gray">
' but the other .html file wont show the datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the complete HTML file it will be difficult to say, but try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <!--this is for my jqgrid-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.fluid.js"></script>
    <!--this is for my other .js files-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="globalFunc.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="tallySheet.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainindex.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prime-settings.js"></script>
    <!--this is for my closable tabs-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.tabs.closable.min.js"></script>
```

You are loading 2 versions of jquery and 3 versions of jquery.ui.  Put jQuery first followed by jQuery.ui. If that doesn't solve the problem, can you post the complete html file?

Comment: hey, thanks for this. It's working though it creates a problem with my closable tabs. But it's really great now. Thanks for the answer. It never really cross my mind about the jquery versions. :) thank you again.

Comment: I was missing the basic jQuery.js file to put above everything in my datepicker test page. It came with the download but in a folder called "external" go figure. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you need a

```
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

somewhere in your markup

Comment: yes kinakuta, I already added that code inside my body tag. But it still doesn't show. Thanks for answering. :) I guess it's how i write my library.

Answer (score 0):

You are right 37Stars, by loading two different version of JQuery you cause the Datepicker's opening fail.